# Linux gateway is forwarding traffic to its own gateway when tunnel is down

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables, tunnel, gateway

I have a box (192.168.1.2) that connects to a VPN creating a tunnel. This box has a 192.168.1.1 default gateway which is my router's internal address. The rest of my network has 192.168.1.2 (aforementioned linux box) as their default gateway (by DHCP). I set up my iptables as follows:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i any -o tun+ -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun+ -j MASQUERADE
```

The idea is that all network traffic goes through the linux box when the tunnel is up and that traffic does not flow when tunnel is down.

I had it working on my previous box but it seems I am missing something in the configuration now.

When the tunnel is up, everything works fine but when the tunnel is down, I can see all my traffic trying 192.168.1.2 and then trying 192.168.1.1 although it is not configured in any of the clients.

tcpdump showed that for ICMP traffic, 192.168.1.2 is sending a REDIRECT message.

I disabled icmp redirect besides that being only for ICMP and not having impact on the rest of the protocols (AFAIU) but the traffic (as I expected) is still flowing through 192.168.1.1 when the tunnel is down.

I disabled accept_source_route and nothing changed.

I have no clue what to look for after a few hours of research. Why is my traffic being forwarded to a gateway that is not configured in my clients?